# Pass parameter to web part

Tags: sharepoint, smartpart

I'm using SmartPart 1.3 to develop web-parts to SharePoint. I need pass parameter to my web-part for example list name. Maybe anybody know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you might be asking to have the option to configure your webpart via a custom ToolPart (WebPart Options => Modify Shared WebPart) and be able to set the list name in a field in the 'sidebar'.

Take a look at [the generic way of doing toolparts at msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd584178(office.11).aspx). In SmartPart you dont have a feature-like way of creating the toolpart, you can use the generic way. I also found [this link in their codeproject page with a C# sample](http://smartpart.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=15243&ANCHOR) (requires tunning)